# How to Preserve HereDoc-Style Comments Inside Function Using UglifyJS2

Tags: javascript, regex, uglifyjs2

I often use empty functions as HereDoc blocks when templating.

```
var heredoc = function() {/*
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
*/};
```

The UglifyJS2 compressor removes all comments, which is generally desirable. Except for this one! I thought to use "--comments" on the command-line and "/** @preserve" in the comment block, which did not work. I also tried regular expressions.  Here is a specific command I tried on the above JS file:

```
uglifyjs test.js -o test.min.js -p 5 -c -m --comments /div/i
```

And the result was as follows:

```
var heredoc=function(){};
```

I'm finding it difficult to get any regular expression to work at all...

```
/* div keep me */
var heredoc = function() {/** @preserve
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
*/};

heredoc();
```

placement of the comment inside or outside; calling the function directly or not. Nothing is working.

uglify-js 2.6.1

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very acceptable answer, but I will offer it anyways.

This is working:

```
var heredoc = function() {/** @preserve
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
*/""};
```

I added the empty string at the bottom after reading another question:

[UglifyJS2 removes wanted comments at the end of a block or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592288/uglifyjs2-removes-wanted-comments-at-the-end-of-a-block-or-file)

However, it did not work using regex. I had to use the jsdoc @preserve tag.